# NodeJS Callback not returning completed array outside for loop

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, callback, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I've got an empty object array "storing" and I'm currently pushing objects in a nested for loop. This issue is when I call the callback(null, storing) outside the for loop it returns an empty array. Should I be running a promise call? Not sure where to go from here

```
var params = {
    TableName: USER_TABLE,
    KeyConditions: {
        orgid: {
            ComparisonOperator: 'EQ',
            AttributeValueList: [org_uuid]
        },
        orgkey: {
            ComparisonOperator: 'EQ',
            AttributeValueList: [secret_key]
        }
    }
};

// query table for devices tied to user
dynamodb.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        badRequest();
    } else {
        // check whether correct org_uuid & org_key has been passed
        var checked_org = data.Items[0].org_key;
        if (checked_org == secret_key) {
    var storing = [];
            var value = data.Items[0].read.values;
            for (var x = 0; x < value.length; x++) {
                var query_params = {
                    TableName: DEVICE_TABLE,
                    KeyConditions: {
                        device_id: {
                            AttributeValueList: {
                                S: value[x]
                            },
                            ComparisonOperator: 'EQ'
                        }
                    }
                };
                dynamodb.query(query_params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++) {
                            storing.push(data.Items[i].device_id);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        callback(null, storing)
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: You don't strictly need Promises. Just avoid making the callback until you have everything you need. As it stands, the callback will be made before the N (value.length) calls to the 2nd dynamodb.query() are complete, which would account for the empty array. You could simply use a counter in the 2nd dynamodb.query callback, for example, and make the callback when you have seen the Nth query complete. Or you could use Promises and Promise.all, of course.

Comment: @jarmod thanks for that reply, if I add the callback with a counter as you suggested in the 2nd db callback, the callback completes only pushes the first object in and returns that. Say if the higher level for loop has a value.length of 3. it only returns the callback when value.length goes through the first loop.

Comment: Whoops @jarmod I think I know what you mean now thanks!